# IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Fibo.py'

Tags: python

This error comes when i try installing python modules.

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Fibo.py'
```

Comment: maybe you're omitting the `sudo` prefix.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre How is the question a duplicate? He asked about installing modules not about installing pip.

Comment: what about that one?